# Perl: Return hashref from function does not work

Tags: perl, function, obfuscation, hashref

I was fooling around with some obfuscated code that doesn't do anything useful when I encountered some strange behaviour I did not understand.

Here's my code.

```
no strict;
sub foo{1&&{${$_[0]},${$_[0]}}}say map {&${${_}}(${_})->{${${_}}}}map{\$_}qw(foo);
```

And in indented:

```
no strict;
sub foo {
  1 && { ${$_[0]} => ${$_[0]} }
}
say map { &${ ${_} }( ${_} )->{ ${ ${_} } } }
  map { \$_ } qw (foo);
```

What it should do is take the string `foo`, build a reference to it, and then call the function with that name (`&foo`). That function should return a hashref where both key and value are said `foo` string. After that, it prints the value of the returned hashref's key `foo`, which is `foo`.

So far, so good. Not useful, but still fun. The strange thing is, when I remove the `1 &&` part in the sub, it returns a list despite the curlies, and I have no clue why it does that.

If I just say `sub foo { { 'foo'=>'foo' } }` it returns the reference. Why doesn't it in my case? And furthermore, why does it when I add `1 &&`?

Comment: I love how perl "readable" is still, more or less unreadable :)

Comment: That is excruciating Perl.  There's barely half an excuse for it when it fits on one line.  If you're using multiple lines, it should be written for clarity, and that isn't (unless there are some explanatory comments that were left out of the question).

Comment: @asf107 He means "indented", not "readable". Normal perl code is perfectly readable, though some code written by happy amateurs looks like a proper mess.

Comment: @TLP: you're right. Since this is not normal code I'd say it doesn't matter. The problem could well have occured in very readable production code. I'm not sure if you called me a happy amateur, though. I certainly am happy. :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That was the point. ;-)

Comment: @simbabque No, not you personally, I was referring to happy amateurs in general. =P

Comment: @asf107, noone claimed "indented" means "readable".

Comment: @ikegami: I edited the post. It said readable first. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the `1 &&` part the curly braces are interpreted as a block thus returning a list. With the additional part the perl interpreter makes an anonymous hashreference as desired.

Instead of the `1 &&` you could also use a simple `+` to help the perl interpreter:

```
sub foo {
  +{ ${$_[0]} => ${$_[0]} }
}
```

Comment: Also, an explicit `return { ... };` would work, I believe (and that is clearer).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure the explicit return would be the best solution but since the post is tagged with obfuscation ... ;)

Comment: It does, but I forgot to put that in. dgw's answer explains what's happening. It didn't occur to me that it would be treated as a block. Makes a lot of sense if you think about it. Thanks for that.